# problem in build.xml

Tags: java, ant

My build.xml is building successfully.But it is not creating or copying all the folders and files. It took only 1 sec for building. I think it have to to round about 1 min. I tried to find out whats wrong by giving echo in different point. I could see that when I put echo somewhere it show the message in the echo two time,somewhere it is not showing. I doubt it is going to torque build.xml file in the project while execution. I am pasting the build.xml here. Please help

```
<property name="build.home" value="build/jsp" />
<property name="tomcat.home" location="../Tomcat 5.0/" />
<path id="project.class.path">
    <fileset dir="./lib/">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="reltag">
    <tstamp>
        <format property="now" pattern="d MMM yyyy HH:mm" />
    </tstamp>
    <property name="reltag" value="Built date: ${now}" />
</target>

<target name="dev" depends="compile" description="Builds for development">
    <mkdir dir="jsp/WEB-INF/lib" />
    <mkdir dir="jsp/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <copy todir="jsp/WEB-INF/lib">
        <fileset dir="lib">
            <exclude name="**/CVS/*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <copy todir="jsp/WEB-INF/classes">
        <fileset dir="classes">
            <exclude name="**/CVS/*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="myproject-gen,reltag">
    <copy file="setup/Version.java.template" tofile="java/myproject/Version.java" overwrite="true">
        <filterset>
            <filter token="VERSION" value="${reltag}" />
        </filterset>
    </copy>
    <mkdir dir="classes" />
    <depend srcdir="java" destdir="classes" cache="depcache" />
    <javac srcdir="java" destdir="classes">
        <classpath refid="project.class.path" />
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="myproject-gen" description="Generates torque classes and SQL for myproject">
    <!-- generate the java files -->
    <ant dir="torque" target="om" />
    <antcall target="myproject-sql-mysql" />
</target>

<!-- generate the schema.sql script for MySQL -->
<target name="myproject-sql-mysql" depends="myproject-sql-mysql-check" unless="mysql.schema.up.to.date">
    <echo message="Generating SQL file for MySQL" />
    <ant dir="torque" target="sql">
        <property name="torque.database" value="mysql" />
        <property name="torque.runOnlyOnSchemaChange" value="false" />
    </ant>
    <move file="sql/gen/myproject-schema.sql" tofile="sql/gen/myproject-schema-mysql.sql" overwrite="true" />
    <copy file="sql/gen/myproject-schema-mysql.sql" tofile="jsp/admin/database.sql" overwrite="true"/>
    <copy file="sql/init.sql" tofile="jsp/admin/init.sql" overwrite="true" />
</target>

<!-- check if we need to generate the sql file -->
<target name="myproject-sql-mysql-check">
    <uptodate property="mysql.schema.up.to.date" targetfile="sql/gen/myproject-schema-mysql.sql" srcfile="torque/myproject-schema.xml" />
</target>


// when i gave the echo inside this target block I was not able to get it and when i gave  the mkdir outside this block it create the folder

<target name="myproject-war" depends="compile-jsp">
    <mkdir dir="build" />
    <jar destfile="build/myproject.war" basedir="build/jsp" />
</target>

<target name="prepare_for_war_file">
    <mkdir dir="build\jsp-classes\org\apache\jsp" />
    <!--
    <move todir="${build.home}/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/jsp">
            <fileset dir="${build.home}">
            <include name="*.jsp"/>
            </fileset>
    </move> 
    -->
    <!-- copy everything which is not a jsp to admin directory -->
    <copy tofile="${build.home}/admin/database.sql">
        <fileset file="sql/gen/*-schema-mysql.sql" />
    </copy>
    <copy file="sql/init.sql" todir="${build.home}/admin" />
    <mkdir dir="${build.home}/pdb_files" />
    <!-- copy images directory -->
    <copy todir="${build.home}/images">
        <fileset dir="jsp/images" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${build.home}/hand">
        <fileset dir="jsp/hand" />
    </copy>
    <!-- copy javascript directory -->
    <copy todir="${build.home}/javascript">
        <fileset dir="jsp/javascript" />
    </copy>
    <!-- copy META-INF directory -->
    <copy todir="${build.home}/META-INF">
        <fileset dir="jsp/META-INF" />
    </copy>
    <!-- copy stylesheet directory -->
    <copy todir="${build.home}/stylesheet">
        <fileset dir="jsp/stylesheet" />
    </copy>
    <!-- copy WEB-INF directory  -->
    <copy todir="${build.home}/WEB-INF/classes/">
        <fileset dir="classes/" includes="**" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${build.home}/WEB-INF/lib">
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.*" excludes="Cabwiz" />
    </copy>
    <!-- copy license and properties -->
    <!--<copy file="WebContent/myproject.license" todir="${build.home}"/> -->
    <copy file="jsp/myproject.properties" todir="${build.home}" />
    <!-- move jsp classes to the correct package structure so war file will work when deployed -->
    <move todir="${build.home}/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/jsp">
        <fileset dir="${build.home}" includes="**/*.class" excludes="WEB-INF/**" />
    </move>
    <antcall target="create-web_XML">
    </antcall>
</target>

<target name="create-web_XML">
    <loadfile property="generated.web.xml" srcFile="jsp/WEB-INF/generated_web.xml" />
    <copy file="jsp/WEB-INF/web_template.xml" tofile="jsp/WEB-INF/web.xml.deployable" overwrite="true">
        <filterset begintoken="&lt;!--" endToken="--&gt;">
            <filter token="GENERATED_WEB_XML" value="${generated.web.xml}" />
        </filterset>
    </copy>
    <copy file="jsp/WEB-INF/web.xml.deployable" tofile="build/jsp/WEB-INF/web.xml" />
</target>

<target name="compile-jsp" depends="dev">
    <antcall target="prepare_for_war_file">
    </antcall>
    <property environment="env" />
    <taskdef classname="org.apache.jasper.JspC" name="jasper2">
        <classpath id="jspc.classpath">
            <pathelement location="${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" />
            <fileset dir="${env.tomcat.home}/bin2">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${env.tomcat.home}/server/lib">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${env.tomcat.home}/common/lib">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <mkdir dir="java/jsp-src" />
    <jasper2 validateXml="false" package="org.apache.jsp" uriroot="jsp" webXmlFragment="jsp/WEB-INF/generated_web.xml" outputDir="java/jsp-src" />
    <jspc srcdir="jsp" destdir="java/jsp-src">
        <include name="include/**/*.jsp" />
        <include name="**/*.jsp" />
    </jspc>
    <mkdir dir="build/jsp-classes" />
    <property environment="env" />
    <javac destdir="build/jsp/WEB-INF/classes" optimize="off" debug="on" failonerror="true" srcdir="java/jsp-src" excludes="**/*.smap">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="classes" />
            <fileset dir="lib">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
            <pathelement location="${env.tomcat.home}/common/classes" />
            <fileset dir="${env.tomcat.home}/common/lib">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
            <pathelement location="${env.tomcat.home}/shared/classes" />
            <fileset dir="${env.tomcat.home}/shared/lib">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${env.tomcat.home}/bin">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
        <include name="**" />
        <!--<exclude name="**/includes/*menu_jsp.java" />-->
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="clean" description="Deletes the java/classes dir and torque base objects">
    <delete dir="classes" />
    <delete dir="${build.home}" />
    <delete>
        <fileset file="build/*" />
    </delete>
    <delete dir="java/myproject/torque/map" />
    <delete dir="java/jsp-src" />
    <delete dir="jsp/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <delete dir="jsp/WEB-INF/lib" />
    <delete>
        <fileset dir="java/myproject/torque" includes="Base*.java" />
    </delete>
    <touch file="torque/myproject-schema.xml" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your build with `ant -v`. It will tell you what it's doing and for some actions even why.

Comment: I am using eclipse .so I am building by right clicking and ren as ant built. I think it is through the command prompt.we have give only ant -v command to run my build file? I am sorry if it is a stupid question,but I am not familiar with it .So plz help

Comment: Change to the directory of the build file and run ant -v

Comment: Bring up the External Tools Configuration in Eclipse.  If you select the ant build, you will see a section called Arguments.  In there add -v (or -debug).

Comment: when i open external tool dialog box.it says that external toollocation does not exist. How can I bring up the external tool configuration. plz help

Answer (score 0):

Run `ant` with `-verbose` mode, it will give you more hints on the problem.

Comment: How to run ant in verbose mode. I dont know. i am entirely new to this.So plz help

Comment: as the following:
ant -verbose

Comment: the ant is in c:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.0v200706080842\bin. So I came upto this in the command prompt and execute the command .Then I got "build failed build.xml does not exist".So shud I copy all the relevant files inside the ant?

Comment: You need to go to the directory where the build.xml file is located. There you type the "ant -verbose"

Comment: when i gave that i got target "verbose" does not exist in the project "MYPROJECT"

Answer (score 0):

Try the ant  debug flag (ant -debug  ). You may have do dump the output to a file and check it.

Comment: i cut the output and check which all folders are not copying and creating. Is this what you meant? how can do the ant -debug flag?:(